# How to block click() on link inside of the element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wasn't sure how to title this issue, but let me explain. I have a box with content, links, and a checkbox inside of it. If you click anywhere in the box, it will mark the checkbox. It will also do this if you click a link. How do I disable the checking of the box if you click a link, instead of the box? (confusing I know, see code snippet below)

```js
$("div").on("click", function() {
  var $checkbox = $(this).find(":checkbox");
  $checkbox.prop("checked", !$checkbox[0].checked);
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: auto;
  background: #999;
  color: #FFF;
}
input {
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris sit amet urna risus. Maecenas egestas pellentesque sapien blandit hendrerit. Morbi tellus felis, elementum ut ligula eu, convallis luctus ante. <a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">Nulla molestie mollis aliquam.</a> Maecenas
    nisl nulla, fringilla et placerat vitae, tempus ut urna.</p>
  <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" class="check">
</div>
```

Comment: Well-asked question!!

Comment: Try to method preventDefault() in javascript.  That prevents the default functionality of the object from being executed.

Comment: I'm confused why you switched the "accepted" answer from Jivan's to Rohit416's? They're effectively the same answer, Jivan just posted it earlier. Obviously you're free to accept whatever answer you want, I'm just asking because the switch makes me wonder if there's a misunderstanding...?

Comment: I totally agree with @T.J.Crowder, if it is doing the same purpose then switching does not make sense. It would be better if you (OP) can hint what was the **actual circumstance** behind the switch so that it clears the intent !!!!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder It's hard to explain cause the code is a bit in depth, but basically when the user clicks inside the box, it does either adds X to a variable or subtracts based on if the checkbox is checked. If you click the link inside of the box, the checkbox doesn't check (which your answer fixed), but it subtracted since i clicked the link (inside box). To fix this, I added the `$('.my-link').click(function(e) { e.stopPropagation(); });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [event.stopPropagation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) on `click` handler attached to `<a>`. As per the definition,

> It prevents further propagation of the current event in the bubbling phase.

Here is the working snippet.

```js
$("div").on("click", function() {
  var $checkbox = $(this).find(":checkbox");
  $checkbox.prop("checked", !$checkbox[0].checked);
});

$('.my-link').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: auto;
  background: #999;
  color: #FFF;
}
input {
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris sit amet urna risus. Maecenas egestas pellentesque sapien blandit hendrerit. Morbi tellus felis, elementum ut ligula eu, convallis luctus ante. <a class="my-link" href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">Nulla molestie mollis aliquam.</a> Maecenas
    nisl nulla, fringilla et placerat vitae, tempus ut urna.</p>
  <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" class="check">
</div>
```

Comment: You are actually the winner for my circumstance (T.J. Crowder is also correct). Thanks a lot man

Comment: I personally like @T.J.Crowder's answer. At the time i was writing i was unaware about other incoming answers and you can see some of them are doing the same thing. Adding class will give you an advantage if you have some other type of elements in a block apart from `a` and you can apply same class on them may be with a different and more meaningful name. Its just that.

Answer (score 6):

By checking whether the click travelled through a link en route to the `div`, using `event.target`:

```
$("div").on("click", function(event) {
  if ($(event.target).closest("a").length) {
      // It travelled through a link, don't do anything
  } else {
    var $checkbox = $(this).find(":checkbox");
    $checkbox.prop("checked", !$checkbox[0].checked);
  }
});
```

Updated snippet:

```js
$("div").on("click", function(event) {
  if ($(event.target).closest("a").length) {
    // It travelled through a link, don't do anything
  } else {
    var $checkbox = $(this).find(":checkbox");
    $checkbox.prop("checked", !$checkbox[0].checked);
  }
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: auto;
  background: #999;
  color: #FFF;
}
input {
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris sit amet urna risus. Maecenas egestas pellentesque sapien blandit hendrerit. Morbi tellus felis, elementum ut ligula eu, convallis luctus ante. <a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">Nulla molestie mollis aliquam.</a> Maecenas
    nisl nulla, fringilla et placerat vitae, tempus ut urna.</p>
  <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" class="check">
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm, impressive :)

Answer (score 4):

I guess a good'ol `stopPropagation` in the link's click handler would do the trick.

```
$("div a").on("click", function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

This [prevents your click from bubbling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) to the div.

Updated snippet:

```js
$("div").on("click", function(event) {
  var $checkbox = $(this).find(":checkbox");
  $checkbox.prop("checked", !$checkbox[0].checked);
});
$("div a").on("click", function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: auto;
  background: #999;
  color: #FFF;
}
input {
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris sit amet urna risus. Maecenas egestas pellentesque sapien blandit hendrerit. Morbi tellus felis, elementum ut ligula eu, convallis luctus ante. <a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">Nulla molestie mollis aliquam.</a> Maecenas
    nisl nulla, fringilla et placerat vitae, tempus ut urna.</p>
  <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" class="check">
</div>
```